# Prove the identity Binomial Series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Use $(1-x)^{2n} = (1-x)^n(1-x)^n$ to prove the identity $${2n \choose n} = \sum_k {n \choose k}^2$$
I converted $(1-x)^{2n}$ into a binomial series yielding $$\sum_{k=0}^{2n} {2n \choose k} (-x)^k$$
And I converted $(1-x)^{n}$ into a binomial series yielding $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} (-x)^k$$
I combined these series to get $${2n \choose k} (-x)^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} (-x)^k {n \choose n-k} (-x)^{n-k}$$
I divided through by $(-x)^k$ to eliminate the x terms and now I am stuck at $${2n \choose k} =\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} {n \choose n-k}$$
Basically I am struggling to connect the final dots and create the punchline of the proof. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have the correct idea but your solution is written very sloppily (and at places, plain wrong). Anyway, recall that ${n \choose k} = {n \choose n - k}$ (just open the definitions or think about this combinatorically).

Comment: you have it!!  you are done, just look at @levap 's comment...

Comment: The last displayed formula is problematic. The left side involves $k$. The right side does not, there $k$ is just a dummy variable of summation, which could be replaced by $j$, or some other letter.

Comment: According to Chu-Vandermonde identity, the last equation should be ${2n \choose n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}{n \choose {n-k}}$. Thus, the derivation is incorrect.

Comment: Thank you @levap ! that was the piece I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's convenient to use the  *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series. So, we can write e.g.
$$\binom{n}{k}=[x^k](1+x)^n$$.

We also use OPs identity in the form $(1+x)^n(1+x)^n=(1+x)^{2n}$, i.e. $x$ replaced by $-x$ which simplifies somewhat the calculation below.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2&=\sum_{k=0}^n[x^k](1+x)^n[y^k](1+y)^n\\
>   &=[x^0](1+x)^n\sum_{k=0}^nx^{-k}[y^k](1+y)^n\tag{1}\\
>   &=[x^0](1+x)^n\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^n\tag{2}\\
>   &=[x^0](1+x)^nx^{-n}(1+x)^n\\
>   &=[x^n](1+x)^{2n}\\
>   &=\binom{2n}{n}
>   \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the rule $[x^k]f(x)=[x^0]x^{-k}f(x)$
- In (2) we use the substitution rule $f(x):=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_kx^k=\sum_{k=0}^n[y^k]f(y)x^k$