# Discrete math evaluate

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Question: Evaluate $$\sum_{k=0}^n {2k\choose k}{2n-2k \choose n-k}$$
Hint: use the fact that $$(1-4x)^{-1/2} = \sum_{n\ge0} {2n \choose n}x^n$$
For some reason the hint has me more lost than the problem but I'm sure it is included for a reason. My gut feeling is to approach this with a binomial series but I am not sure where to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: the hint is just a case of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Comment: Try to justify the following - $\left(\sum a_m x^m\right) \cdot \left(\sum b_m x^m\right) = \sum_n x^n \left(\sum_{k = 0}^n a_k b_{n-k}\right)$. Once you have that, squaring $(1-4x)^{-1/2}$ does the job.

Comment: another hint https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways to find a closed expression

**Cauchy product**

Note, the binomial expression in OPs question is a Cauchy product which we get as the coefficient of the multiplication of two power series. In case both series are equal, say $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
A^2(x)=\left(\sum_{n\geq0}a_nx^n\right)^2
=\sum_{n\geq0}\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_ka_{n-k}\right)x^n\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> Applying  (1) and using the hint stated in OPs question with $a_n=\binom{2n}{n}$ we get
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n\geq0}&\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\right)x^n\\
> &=\left(\sum_{n\geq0}\binom{2n}{n}x^n\right)^2\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\right)^2\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-4x}\\
> &=\sum_{n\geq 0}4^nx^n
> \end{align*}

We conclude by comparing coefficients

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=4^n\qquad\qquad n\geq 0
\end{align*}

**Coefficient of - operator**

Another way is to use the *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ of a series $A(x)=\sum_{k\geq 0}a_kx^k$ analogously to *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557024/prove-the-identity-binomial-series/1558077#1558077)*.

> We obtain for $n\geq 0$
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^n&\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n[x^k]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}[y^{n-k}]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4y}}\\
> &=[y^n]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4y}}\sum_{k=0}^ny^k[x^k]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\tag{2}\\
> &=[y^n]\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4y}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4y}}\tag{3}\\
> &=[y^n]\frac{1}{1-4y}\\
> &=[y^n]\sum_{n\geq 0}4^ny^n\\
> &=4^n
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we use the rule $[y^k]f(y)=[y^0]y^{-k}f(y)$
- In (3) we use the substitution rule $f(y):=\sum_{k=0}^{n}a_ky^k=\sum_{k=0}^n\left([x^k]f(x)\right)y^k$